# NodeJs Promises - Trying to run async along with wait

Tags: node.js

I have some Nodejs code and it results

```
mainFunction();

async function mainFunction(){

    console.log("Start")
    await deleteDSStore(cardsFolder);
    console.log("Done")


}

async function deleteDSStore(folder){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
            files.forEach(async(file) => {
                if(file == ".DS_Store"){
                    fs.unlinkSync(folder+file);
                    console.log("Deleted File" + file);
                }
                else if(fs.lstatSync(folder+file).isDirectory()) {
                    await deleteDSStore(folder+file+"/");
                    console.log("was waiting");
                } else {
                    console.log("nothing");
                }
            });
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Result

```
Start
Done
was waiting
was waiting
```

I want to see more like

```
Start
was waiting
was waiting
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` is an async "runner" meaning that this code will happen eventually but you are not waiting for the `forEach` to finish its execution.

you can use `for of` or `for in` or simply

```
 await Promise.all(_.map(files, async(file) => {
                if(file == ".DS_Store"){
                    fs.unlinkSync(folder+file);
                    console.log("Deleted File" + file);
                }
                else if(fs.lstatSync(folder+file).isDirectory()) {
                    await deleteDSStore(folder+file+"/");
                    console.log("was waiting");
                } else {
                    console.log("nothing");
                }
            })
)
```

here _ is loadsh.

Comment: Why does your text say to use `for/of` and instead your code uses lodash?  I see absolutely no reason to need or require lodash here.

Comment: if you will read my text with attention I said that you can use `for of` *OR* the code snippet iv'e wrote here.

Comment: Yea, so why does your code introduce lodash here then?