# NodeJS: product color model problem with the async await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

In this code i'm getting the colors string which be like (Red, Green, Blue)
and i'm converting it into an array of colors.
Then i loop throw this array and search in my mongodb database in the colors collection if the color already exists.

If it is, then i will push the document id into the colorsDocIds and push the product id into the colorDocument.product and then i save the document to update it with the new product id which was pushed.

If the doesn't exist in the collection, then i will create one and push the new color document id into the constant. and finally i put colorsDocIds into the product.colors field.

The problem is when i try to make that somehow when i do that the colors field in the product document may have the array of ids and sometimes it doesn't have. and i see that this problem maybe related to async/await.

```
  const colorsArray = colors.split(',').map((color) => color.trim());
  const colorsDocIds = [];

  colorsArray.forEach(async (color) => {
    const colorDocument = await Color.findOne({ color });

    if (!colorDocument) {
      const newColor = await Color.create({ product: product.id, color });
      colorsDocIds.push(newColor.id);
    } else {
      colorsDocIds.push(colorDocument.id);
      colorDocument.product.push(product.id);
      await colorDocument.save();
    }
  });

  product.colors = colorsDocIds;
  await product.save();
```

Comment: Solved by changing forEach with map and surrounding it with Promise.all
await Promise.all(colorsArray.map(async (color) => {})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs Promises - Trying to run async along with wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226968/nodejs-promises-trying-to-run-async-along-with-wait)

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this answer:

[NodeJs Promises - Trying to run async along with wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226968/nodejs-promises-trying-to-run-async-along-with-wait/69227064?noredirect=1#comment122360022_69227064)

the problem you have is with the for each which run in an async way.